# Arduino first-blink-function

Tags: arduino

I have started working with Arduino Nano. I'm trying to choose the port, but I haven't got 'usbserial' port

I think, that I need some **drivers**, but I don't know, where can I get them.

I work on Mac
Thank you, anyway

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the FTDI drivers found[here](http://www.ftdichip.com/Drivers/VCP.htm)

The complete setup procedure can be found [Here](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/MacOSX)